# 404 Error with mybinder.org when I try to deploy a Jupyter Notebook with voila from GitHub

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, voila, mybinder

I have a problem deploying my Jupyter Notebook from Github to mybinder.org.
I configured everything according to several tutorials I found, but everytime I try to build the page mybinder.org gives me this error afterwards:

**404 : Not Found,
You are requesting a page that does not exist!**

The building process seems to work, as there are no error messages despite the 404 error in the end.

This is my Github page I try to build from: https://github.com/MkengineTA/VoilaDemo

And here you can see the input I use on mybinder.org:

[image: Mybinder Input]

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is building just fine right now. I'm looking at it in Voila. I think though you aren't using the right link to launch direct. (Investigating that next.) The way I tested was what you want to do for developing/testing via mybinder as starting point: I just put in your repo in the form on the top line and NOTHING ELSE and press launch. That will open the session in JupyterLab and you can click on the notebook and open it. Then click the Voila icon along the toolbar just above the notebook. The Voila panel will open if all is good, as it is with your repo/code right now.

Comment: About the link constructed to allow direct launch to Voila render ... Simple error. In the form you show, you didn't type the correct name of the notebook in your 'URL to open'. The resulting correct address should be: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/MkengineTA/VoilaDemo/main?urlpath=voila%2Frender%2FTestVoila.ipynb , that's `https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/MkengineTA/VoilaDemo/main?urlpath=voila%2Frender%2FTestVoila.ipynb`. You had the name of the notebook wrong in what the form was generating because you input the name of the repo and not the notebook there in front of `.ipynb`.

Comment: By the way, I should add that after you press launch, you can watch the image build from the repo if you toggle 'Show' on the left side of 'Build logs' near bottom of page. If it's already built sucessfully it will try to launch the session. Usually the 'building' step people talk about in trouble-shooting MyBinder issues is at that step. Getting the image to build from the repo can be the most difficult part. It's not "build the page", as you word it. That is simply serving the right page from the session. Sometimes that target page won't exist, for example if you forgot to install Voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't have the correct name of the notebook in the 'URL to open' portion of the form.

The resulting correct address should be: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/MkengineTA/VoilaDemo/main?urlpath=voila%2Frender%2FTestVoila.ipynb , that's `https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/MkengineTA/VoilaDemo/main?urlpath=voila%2Frender%2FTestVoila.ipynb`.

You had the name of the notebook wrong in what the form was generating because you input the name of the repo and not the notebook there in front of `.ipynb`.