# Voila - Extra padding for cells with no output

Tags: html, css, pandas, jupyter-notebook, voila

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook to build a pdf page using the Voila package (I use Voila to make the render, and then print the page as a PDF) and I have noticed that cells without an output still put padding into the Voila render. I am unsure how to fix this and it is wreaking havoc on my formatting. Please see example below.

[Jupyter Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5M8g.png)

[Voila Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdsIQ.png)

I am running Voila 0.3.6 and Jupyter 1.0.0 and pandas 1.5.1.

I found a similar question posted to the [Voila issues board in 2019](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/387), but it should be resolved so I am unsure how to proceed.

EDIT: I used `pip install [insert software here] --upgrade --user` to install updates and now have Voila 0.4.0 and notebook 6.5.2.

EDIT: This issue appears to be an updating problem and I have posted it on the [Jupyter Community Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-update-voila-to-resolve-the-padding-of-empty-cells/17028) as well.

Comment: You need to use the latest tech to benefit from the updates. You can see it works correctly when you have the current underlying tech by clicking [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/voila-dashboards/voila/stable?urlpath=voila%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks) and in that temporary session drag-n-drop in your test notebook (which ideally you would have shared as a gist with your post to sae others typing) to the file browser on the left. Open it and then click the Voila icon on the right side of the toolbar along the top. You'll see it doesn't happen in Voila like your image. I just tested it myself.

Comment: That launch linked I used can be access from [the Voila GitHub repo](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) by going there and clicking the `launch binder` badge. As underlying tech, I suspect you need the new server and not the old stuff. Specifically from what you list, `Jupyter 1.0.0` doesn't sound up-to-date to me.

Comment: I should add that it is possible to view the voila rendering as a full page from the sessions as well. The page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74604898/8508004), and answer start to give you some insight how you can launch direct. You can also learn how to switch the mode after-the-fact using the end of the URL by looking at some examples and learning the pattern and adapting it to your already-running sessions. I'm pointing this ability out so you can see that there is a a way to test that it isn't just the voila panel view in JupyterLab that is displaying as it should.

Comment: Hey Wayne, Thanks for responding! I used pip to install updates for voila, Jupyter, and notebook. Jupyter 1.0.0 seems to be the most updated, notebook updated to 6.5.2, and voila updated to 0.4.0. Do you know of any additional modules that should be installed / updated? I also tried using the binder tool you provided, but was unable to run any personal notebooks.

Comment: You need to drag-n-drop in your personal notebooks from your local system into the file browser panel on the left side when JupyterLab opens to add them into remote session machine. Then you can use them there. As for updating, my suspicions are that you aren't using the new server that comes with JupyterLab or pip alone isn't enough to give you the tech needed. I wonder if posting at the Jupyter Discourse Community Forum might be a better suggestion. You can use your example padding issue as reason to know you need something better/newer but ask how you should go about it?

Comment: You aren't supposed to cross-post the same question and multiple sites without linking to each cross-post at each site. Also, I suggested you could post about updating your Voila correctly so that it would no longer exhibit that phenomenon. I've already showed you that it isn't something that happens with up-to-date tech.

Comment: Hey Wayne, I am new to these kinds of boards so I was unaware of the etiquette. I have adjusted both posts and referenced them in each.

Comment: No problem. Just trying to keep things on track. Discouraging unacknowledged cross-posting is to help the people helping you & you as well. The idea is that it wastes people's time if they don't know about the other places & all offer the same advice in in each place it is posted. The other aspect that it makes it easier for you & others following in your footsteps later. Imagine a year from now you, or someone else, encounter a similar situation and go searching for help. Future you, or someone else, may find one of the posts but not the others unless they are linked.